# Building an executable fat jar with gradle-script-kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have just moved my build script over to use gradle-script-kotlin, using the gradle 3.4 and gradle-script-kotlin 0.6.

I can get the build script to produce a jar, but the manifest does not include the main class name. I have tried the main class name with Kt and KT at the end based on other posts I have found.

The build script is as follows:

```
 /*
 *    Copyright 2017 SixRQ Ltd.
 *
 *    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *    You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *    limitations under the License.
 */

group = "com.sixrq"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { setUrl("http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1")  } 
        gradleScriptKotlin()
    } 

    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlinModule("gradle-plugin"))
    }
}

plugins {
    application
    groovy
    java
}

apply {
    plugin("kotlin")
}

repositories {
    maven { setUrl("http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1") }
    mavenCentral() 
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlinModule("stdlib"))
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1-M04")
    compile("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.7.4")
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4")
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}

configure<ApplicationPluginConvention> {
    mainClassName = "com.sixrq.kaxb.main.SchemaGenerator"
}
```

I also want to create a fat jar with the runtime dependencies included, I can see plenty of examples of this for a groovy build script but nothing for gradle-script-kotlin, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Application plugin is not the right place, this is used for the generation of run scripts. In order to set the main class in the jar you need to use the following:

```
import org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar
```

and

```
val jar: Jar by tasks
jar.apply {
    manifest.attributes.apply {
        put("Main-Class", "com.sixrq.kaxb.main.SchemaGenerator")
    }
}
```

in the Kotlin Script build file